# how to delegate on ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know jquery support delegate function for add and remove a function custom follow event. EX

```
$("body").delegate("#p", "click", cfunc);
```

but how to delegate function when page loaded ?

edited------

I show more ex code for more detail in my question: :)

i have a function custom name = `cfunc()`
now i need call it when page load for run many many event inside it.

on the time page loaded, viewer make some event (ex: resize, scroll ...) i need `undelegate` `cfunc()` and call again with some new var.

--- edit 2 -----

sorry everyone, i will write done more code :

this is function i want to delegate

```
function bbbb_scroll(pos)
    {
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            var _currentpos = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (_currentpos > pos) {
                console.log('match');
            }
        });
    }
```

now i want add it on to page when stage READY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).delegate("body", "resize", bbbb_scroll);
    });
```

after all, when user `resize` the window of browser, i need `undelegate` `bbbb_scroll` function and call again with new var ( on `pos` variable  )

Comment: FYI: `delegate` is deprecated in favour of `on`. [source](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: By using `$(document).ready`?

Comment: why do you need to delegate that?  It's just `$(document).ready(function(){code here})` or $(function(){code here});

Comment: `$(function(){ //doc loaded });` also works as I have found

Comment: @mic You're right - my bad - I must be tired :-)

Comment: You mean `$(function() { ...})` or `$(window).load(function() { ... })`

Comment: i have just some more my think i want . because i don't know if i call a function with normal way and then i can undelegate it or not?

Comment: @Jamiec: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method`. However `delegate` has not been marked as deprecated...yet anyway. There is a difference. Method marked as deprecated may be removed in any future version of jquery without any further warning and should therefore not be used. Methods simply superseded but not marked as deprecated will stay until deprecated and are still safe to use. See list of deprecated features here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: You can unbind an event like this: $(body).unbind('click');

Comment: @CristiPufu : this case i want call and reject a function, not event :(. that's so hard.

Comment: @Rueta: You should really show some proper code you are currently trying to use as using hypothetical discussions to determine how to do something will be very difficult for anyone to grasp what it is exactly you want.

Comment: I think you should provide more details about the context, and about the events you say the users do that need to `undelegate` the function and call it again. Even show us some code. I just don't think your application logic is correct.

Comment: ok, everyone, sorry for less detail. Because it is my think but i don't done code so i write some description follow. pls help me :(

Comment: i updated my post, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var position = 100;

    var scrollCallback = function(pos){

        var _currentpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (_currentpos > pos) {
            console.log('match');
        }
    };

    var resizeCallback = function(){

        $(document).unbind('scroll');

        $(document).on('scroll', function(){

            scrollCallback(position);

        });
    };

    $(window).on('resize', resizeCallback);

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: yeah!. thanks friend!. This is right way !. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty obvious this one

Have a look at [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //- do your stuff    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You delegate a function to run when the document loads by passing a function (either anonymously or by name) to the `ready` method

Anonymous method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ...
});
```

named function

```
function myReadyHandler(){..}

$(document).ready(myReadyHandler);
```